# Prevent ^X^F from expanding $HOME

Tags: autocompletion, insert-mode, path

For example, I want to write

```
$HOME/.vim/
```

and complete the path with `i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F` so that it becomes:

```
$HOME/.vim/syntax/
```

But what I get is:

```
/home/username/.vim/syntax/
```

One workaround I've tried is using `~` instead of `$HOME`, but they aren't equivalent, e.g. `"echo "$HOME"` is not the same as `echo "~"`, and `~` doesn't help with other environment variables.

Comment: Note that the `^X^F` completion doesn't use bash, it's built in to Vim itself.

Comment: From a quick reading of the source, it seems that this is not possible. In `edit.c`, `ins_compl_get_exp()` is called, which expands all environment variables (as well as patterns like `%:h`). On the next line, the tilde seems to be actually *re-added* with `tilde_replace()`... You could override the `^X^F` completion with your own version though...

Comment: I see what you mean: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/edit.c#L4398

Comment: AFAIK Shougo's [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) will do what you want, by default, using its `file` completion source.

Comment: Permalink for previous comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/5f1fea28f5bc573e2430773c49e95ae1f9cc2a25/src/edit.c#L4398

Answer (score 2):

This is probably impossible without any plugins, as mentioned on the comments.

But you wouldn't have to start from the scratch if you want to implement such functionality using VimL, you could use the [BufNameComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4313) as a starting point (note that it uses the [CompleteHelper : Generic functions to support custom insert mode completions](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914) plugin, which probably isn't necessary for your problem).

You could use a regex to identify any environment variables before the expansion and then apply `substitute(result, expanded_env_var, original_env_var, '')` in order to restore the environment variables.

(actually this works if you want to check only for the first environment variable on the input; if you want to preserve all of them,you would need to build a dictionary with all the variables and the respective expansions, and then iterate on it to replace each expansion with the original variable)